# How to specify custom HTTP error on response in Resteasy service

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jax-rs

In my resteasy service i want to return media files on clients' requests, like this:

From server side (tomcat 6):

```
@GET
@Path("/getXML/{skinId}/{key}")
@Produces("text/xml")
public Response getXMLResource(@PathParam("key") String key, @PathParam("skinId") String skinId) {
  // Reading a file from disk...
  return Response.ok(file, type).build();
}
```

And from clients' side:

```
final URL uri = new URL("http://localhost:8080/service/getXML");
final InputStream stream = uri.openStream();
```

The problem:

I want to return custom HTTP error (resource isn't exist; server is busy, try later).

```
@GET
@Path("/getError")
@Produces("text/xml")
public Response getError() {
  return Response.serverError().status(333).build();
}
```

But when i'm trying to access the error method, i get 500 (!) (in any case) internal server error.

Could you guys help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coped with this.
The problem was in using

```
.serverError()
```

that automaticaly means 500 error code as a server internal.

We can just set status of response to return right status:

```
@GET
@Path("/getError")
public Response getError() {
  return Response.status(412).build();
}
```